# Setting up a digital drum pad to play notes chromatically

Tags: midi, midi-controller-drums

I'm going through the user manual for the software I received with the purchase of an MPD 226 digital drum pad. At this particular point in the manual I'm being told that after loading a bass sound I can now play the drum pads in numerical order to receive chromatic playback of the bass sample. Unfortunately I'm hearing them in a random order and I'm a little confused... I know there's some way to change that but I think it will mess up the way the hardware interacts with the software. Not sure. Kind of at a standstill here though, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you buy it used?  My main approach would be to go through the pads and verify which midi node is assigned to each of them.  Also note that there is a mode note info (instead of sysex etc.) -- make sure it is set in that.